# This bootstrap button dropdown is not working. But why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At first I was using regular html but the dropdown button wasn't working so I changed to jsfiddle to test it out. I saw that the dropwdown still didn't work.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ugpqxpn6/2/

```
<div>

<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

I don't understand why it wouldn't work. I took a look at some similar questions and saw that maybe not including jquery was my problem so I added it but it still seems to malfunction. Can anybody help?

Comment: Check the console, pretty much says it all - Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery.

Comment: I added jquery.min.js in the resources tab on the left in the jsfiddel, it still doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You need to put your `.js` files before your bootstrap.css files

Comment: @ParadoxicalEnigma that's because the load order is messed up, you should have jquery before bootstrap's js (also take a look at the jquery version, I believe you'll need v1.9.1+).

Comment: I see now guys. Can't believe I didn't look at the console for this before. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle with bootstrap.min.js and jquery.min

https://jsfiddle.net/nrgxh5rr/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ohh, ok. I see, I guess it was just the order of the libraries in my original code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 on your keyboard to see the developer console, you have a Javascript error:

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Make sure you're including jQuery before bootstrap's js files.